# Where can I get Twisted ? Official site seems hacked

Tags: python, twisted

[the official site of Twisted](http://twistedmatrix.com) is down (parked by advertisment). I just bought a book about Twisted Network Programming Essentials. Chapter 1 is getting Twisted and setting it up. But with the site down, I don't find where to download Twisted and get extra docs about it.

Could somebody point me to a mirror ?

Comment: Is this really a programming question?

Comment: sure, it is a question about obtaining vital sources without which certain programming tasks could not be accomplished.

Comment: I'm glad that everything got sorted out, but what you didnt realize is Jean-Paul Calderone is one of the people behind the amazing thing we call Twisted.

Answer (score 0):

You could download it from pypi:

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Twisted

Answer (score 0):

Ok so thanks to the people at linuxfr.org and on twisted irc channel, we now know we can access the site from http://66.35.39.65/trac/ and that the site will be back shortly. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

The official site was not "hacked", its domain name registration expired for a couple of hours.  The problem has since been corrected.